# How are these terms derived using recurrence relations in the Gambler's ruin example?

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, markov-chains, markov-process, stopping-times

I have an example in my Stochastic processes book where we find the general probability of the hitting time with intial point $i$ . I'm not sure about one thing though. Here's the example:

(Gambler’s ruin on $0, . . . , N$). Asymmetric random walk on the integers
$0, 1, . . . , N$, with absorption at $0$ and $N$. $0 < p = 1 − q < 1$.

[image]

Let $h_i=P_i( \text{hit $0$})$. So $h_0=1, h_N=0$ and $h_i=qh_{i-1}+ph_{i+1}$ , $1 \leq i \leq N-1$.

Characteristic equation is $px^2-x+q=(x-1)(px-q)$ **[I understand how this is solved].**

So roots are $\{1, {q \over p}\}$ and if $p \neq q$ general solution is $h_i=A+B({q \over p})^i$. **[This I don't understand- what is A and B here?]**

Using boundary conditions we find

$$h_i=\frac{(\frac{q}{p})^i - (\frac{q}{p})^N}{1 - (\frac{q}{p})^N}$$ **[How is this derived??]**

If $p = q $ general solution is $h_i = A + B_i$ and using boundary conditions we get $h_i =
1 − i/N$.**[why?]**

My understanding of recurrence relation isn't that deep so maybe that's why I don't understand this. If someone could explain how these things are derived that would be really helpful!

Comment: In the recurrence $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.  But you also have to satisfy other constraints, in this case the boundary conditions $h_0=1, h_N=0$

Comment: @Henry ok, so How do we get $h_i=\frac{(\frac{q}{p})^i - (\frac{q}{p})^N}{1 - (\frac{q}{p})^N}$?

Comment: What do $A+B({q \over p})^0 = 1$ and $A+B({q \over p})^N = 0$ suggest are the solutions for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: ok yes! I got it! Thanks! $A= \frac{-(q/p)^N}{1-(q/p)^N}$ and $B= \frac{1}{1-(q/p)^N}$